# Writing an struct in shared memory atomically

Tags: cuda, gpgpu, nvcc

For accessing structures, `nvcc` generates a code to read/write the structure field-by-field. Having this structure:

```
typedef struct cache_s {
    int tag;
    TYPE data;
} cache_t;
```

Following PTX code is generated to write a variable of this type to shared memory:

```
st.shared.f64   [%rd1+8], %fd53;
st.shared.u32   [%rd1], %r33;
```

This can raise a logical error in the execution of programs. If two concurrent threads of a thread block write back different values at the same shared memory address, fields from different structures may mix-up. CUDA Programming Guide states:

> If a non-atomic instruction executed by a warp writes to the same
>   location in global or shared memory for more than one of the threads
>   of the warp, the number of serialized writes that occur to that
>   location varies depending on the compute capability of the device (see
>   Compute Capability 2.x, Compute Capability 3.x, and Compute Capability
>   5.x), and which thread performs the final write is undefined.

From this, I expect one of the threads writes its complete structure (whole the fields together) and I don't expect the mix of the fields (from different writes) form an undefined value. Is there a way to force nvcc to generate the code that I expect?

**More Information:**

NVCC Version: 7.5

Comment: No. Your expectations are unrealistic/wrong.

Comment: `From this, I expect one of the threads writes its complete structure (whole the fields together)`: I would be really interested in finding out how you arrive at that conclusion by reading the section you quoted from the CUDA Programming Guide.

Comment: @RogerDahl I was under impression that the location might be extendable to variable.

Comment: @talonmies I assume using an atomic lock on shared memory is a workaround, a terrible solution though. Is there a better solution?

Comment: What you are really saying is "I want my hardware to support completely arbitrary memory transaction sizes", and that can't happen on the GPU, or any platform I am familiar with, current or historical.

Answer (score 2):

> This can raise a logical error in the execution of programs. If two concurrent threads of a thread block write back different values at the same shared memory address, fields from different structures may mix-up.

If you need a complete result from one thread in the block while discarding the results from the other threads, just have one of the threads (thread 0 is often used for this) write out its result and have the remaining threads skip the write:

```
__global__ void mykernel(...)
{
    ...
    if (!threadIdx.x) {
        // store the struct
    }
}
```

> Is there a way to force nvcc to generate the code that I expect?

You want to see NVCC generate a single instruction that does an atomic write of a complete struct of arbitrary size. There is no such instruction, so, no, you can't get NVCC to generate the code.

> I assume using an atomic lock on shared memory is a workaround, a terrible solution though. Is there a better solution?

We can't tell you what would be a better solution because you haven't told us what the problem is that you're trying to solve. In CUDA, atomic operations are typically used only for locking a single 32- or 64-bit word during a read-modify-write operation so wouldn't be a good fit for protecting a complete structure.

There are are parallel operations, sometimes called parallel primitives, such as "reduce" and "scan", that allow many types of problems to be solved without locking. For instance, you might first start a kernel in which each thread writes its results to a separate location then start a new kernel that performs a parallel reduce to pick the result you need.